# What replaced SndVol.exe on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, volume-mixer

In versions of windows previous to 10, the sound volume was an executable `%windir%\System32\SndVol.exe`. While this is still available on Windows 10, it still launches the older volume control rather than the newer Windows 10 one.

Is there a similar executable to call for the newer volume control that arrived with windows 10?

**Old volume control:**

[image: old volume control]

**New volume Control**

[image: new volume control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s part of the Windows Shell Experience Host (`ShellExperienceHost.exe`) that also hosts the Start Menu and all the other tray popups. It’s not a regular Windows program but a Windows Universal App.

You can easily check in Task Manager. The app is suspended when you don’t interact with it but woken up when you open the volume control:

[image: suspended app]

[image: not suspended]

We could probably help you achieve your goal more easily if you asked the actual question though. ;)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I wanted to create a shortcut (or some other way) to allow me to change the volume from keyboard shortcut (standard keyboard, no special volume function keys). Happy enough to figure that part out by myself though now I have a starting point :)

Comment: There are many possibilities to achieve this, for example [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm). No need to “hack it”: Windows offers APIs for this.